# Remove rows on multiple column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame

```
pd_sequences
Out[3]: 
         0   1   2    3    4  5  occurence  unique      dist
0       58  68  58   59   -1 -1          5       3  0.030624
1       59  69  59   58   -1 -1         15       3  0.026485
2       93  94  93   33   -1 -1         10       3  0.137149
3       58  59  58   68   -1 -1          8       3  0.028127
4       92  94  92   33   -1 -1          4       3  0.155580
5       59  58  59   69   -1 -1         10       3  0.026057
```

where the first 6 column names are named as 0,1,2,3,4,5

I would like to drop all rows in that data frame if any of the columns 0 to 5 contain the number 100 or 101.

For a single column that is easy:

```
#remove 100
pd_sequences.drop(pd_sequences[pd_sequences['0'] == 100].index, inplace=True)
```

and then

```
#remove 101
pd_sequences.drop(pd_sequences[pd_sequences['0'] == 101].index, inplace=True)
```

what will be an easy way to include all the columns without making my boolean expression too lengthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of `isin` and `any`, and negate the condition with `~`:

```
pd_sequences[~pd_sequences[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']].isin([100, 101]).any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function which implements your deletion conditions, then apply this function to select the rows:

```
# This column represents rows satisfying the condition
bool_column = df.apply(lambda x: True if x[0] == 100 or x[1] == 101 else False, axis=1)
filtered_df = df[col.values]  # Select rows with True condition
filtered_df = df[~col.values]  # Select rows with False condition
```

Here this function is implemented as lambda but in the case of more complex computations it can be a normal Python function. If there are too many columns involved in the condition then this also could be automated by looping through df.columns. Also, you can pass additional parameters to the function if necessary in the df.apply.